# How do I add ScrollPane to a panel in Java?

Tags: java, swing

I want to add different buttons, vertically stacked, to a `JPanel` at run-time and use a `JScrollPane` so that all buttons will be visible (with some scrolling).

In order to do this, I have added my `JPanel` to a `JScrollPane`, after which I add buttons to my `JPanel`.

However, when I do this the vertical scrollbar does not allow me to see all images.  For example when I add 7 buttons I can only scroll to see 5 full images and half of the 6 images.

Why doesn't my scrollbar allow me to display all 7 buttons?

Comment: Please post any relevant source code.  thanks.

Comment: can any body tell me how can I add a code here.... should I add it in a comment section??

Comment: To add code, you can edit your question and use the "101010" button to format the selection: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create the panel and scrollpane like:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( panel );
```

When you add buttons to the panel at run time the code should be:

```
panel.add( button );
panel.revalidate();
```

As long as you are using a layout manager the preferred size will be recalculated and the scrollbar will appear.

Comment: Better to revalidate the scroll pane.  Revalidating the panel does not always work.

Comment: I've never had a problem. Make sure the code is done on the EDT. Make sure you haven't hard coded the preferred size of the panel.

Answer (score 3):

Make scroll pane a wrapper over your panel - `new JScrollPane (myPanel)` and add it instead of naked panel in your panel's container.

You also may want to play with its `setPreferredSize()` method.

Comment: playing with setPreferredSize() is what I was looking for... Thank you.